# Stark White Navigation Controller

Tags: ios, swift, interface-builder

I want my navigation controller to be stark white, like actual rgb(255, 255, 255, 1) or #ffffff. However, when I set the navigation controller color in the app delegate, it actually becomes a kind of ugly gray. I don't think it is an opacity thing but I can't be sure. Can I get some help?

```
 UINavigationBar.appearance().backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you try to set the navigationbar's translucent attribute to false?

```
    navigationController?.navigationBar.translucent = false
```

Comment: Silly me, thats the answer. If anyone wants it in their app delegate it is:  UINavigationBar.appearance().translucent = false

Comment: @DylanModesitt You should accept this answer if it worked for you.

Comment: There is a time limit... I did it as soon as I could bud ;)